# Custom CSS in WordPress does not work

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using WordPress to create pages for my website. I have the CustomCSS Plugin but it does not seem to be fully working properly.

I want **borders around my radio button Images when selected**.

I made an HTML/CSS playground to see if its an issue with my CSS or WordPress and it appears its WordPress' issue. The playground shows exactly what I want.

How do I get this working on WordPress if I have the exact same code copied into my CustomCSS Plugin and WordPress HTML page?

Playground:

```css
.row{
    font-size: 0px; 
    min-height:50px;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:2%;
}

.third-row{
    display:inline-block;
    width:25%;
    margin:4%;
    height:25px;
}

.input-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.cusimg {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;}

.submit-button {
  padding: 50px: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}

.middle {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.third-row:hover .cusimg {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.third-row:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
 opacity: 3;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}


input[type="radio"]:checked + label img {
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="third-row">
          <input type="radio" name="styleid" value="2" id="2" class="input-hidden" />
          
      <label for="2">
        <img class="cusimg" src="https://cdn-images.gabrielny.com/is/image/GabrielCo/Medium/Gabriel-Chelsea-Platinum-Round-Straight-Engagement-Ring~ER10044PT3JJ-3.jpg" />
      </label>
        </div>
        <div class="third-row">
          <input type="radio" name="styleid" value="1" id="1" class="input-hidden" />
      <label for="1">
        <img class="cusimg" src="https://image.brilliantearth.com/media/shape_images/V3/BE1AS8PD08_RD75_SQ1_PE150_MQ1_white.jpg" />
      </label>
        </div>
        <div class="third-row">
          <input type="radio" name="styleid" value="3" id="3" class="input-hidden" />
      <label for="3">
        <img class="cusimg" src="https://ak1.ostkcdn.com/images/products/9628886/P16814617.jpg" />
      </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself.

Its supposed to be "~" instead, probably something to do with compability with CSS3? not sure.

```
input.input-hidden[type="radio"]:checked ~ label img{
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```